# canvas animation unintentionally drawn using multiple imgdata

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas, filereader

I have a div that contains an img tag and a canvas. When I drag an image into the div, the img.src changes, the new picture appears, and in the canvas, a pointillization animation using the data from the img tag is drawn.

When I drag and drop imgA into the div, imgA appears in the img tag, and the canvas does the animation using imgA, which is what I want.

**The problem is here:**

From this point, if I drag and drop imgB into the div, imgB appears in the img tag, BUT, the canvas animation uses imgA + imgB data.

I think what I did is this:

1. I drag and drop an image into the div.
2. The img.src changes
3. Once theimg is loaded, i resize and clear the canvas
4. I draw the new img on the canvas
5. Function pointillize takes the new canvas data and uses it in the animation which it draws onto the canvas

I thought it had something to do with clearRect() and I tried implementing some of the suggestions but I don't think it's that. I added a click event listener to the document and it does indeed clear the canvas.

**Could it have something to do with setInterval?** I'm just thinking now that maybe, when the new image is loaded it triggers setInterval to run **concurrently** to the previous setInterval()? Maybe the solution is to kill all previous setInterval functions upon loading a new img?

EDIT: It works perfectly now. I declared draw a global variable, and inside function pointillize() I clearInterval(draw) before I set draw = setInterval(). This wipes the setInterval function clean before I start a new one.

html:

```
<div id='container'>
  <img id='output' src='file.jpg'/>
</div>
```

javascript

```
var container, output;
var c, ctx, draw; // draw is declared here as a global variable

window.onload = function(e) {

  c = document.createElement('canvas');
  ctx = c.getContext('2d');
  document.getElementById('container').appendChild(c);

  output = document.getElementById('output');
  output.width = '400';

  container = document.getElementById('container');
  container.style.border = '2px dashed rgb(200, 200, 200)';
  container.style.padding = '6px';

  container.addEventListener('dragenter', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    this.style.border = '2px dashed rgb(50, 50, 50)';
  }, false);    

  container.addEventListener('dragover', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    this.style.border = '2px dashed rgb(50, 50, 50)';
  }, false);

  container.addEventListener('dragleave', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    this.style.border = '2px dashed rgb(200, 200, 200)';
  }, false);

  container.addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    this.style.border = '2px dashed rgb(200, 200, 200)';

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
      output.src = e.target.result;

      // once the new src img is loaded
      output.onload = function() {

        c.width = output.width;
        c.height = output.height;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
        ctx.drawImage(output, 0, 0, output.width, output.height);
        pointillize(ctx);

      }     

    }, false);

    reader.readAsDataURL(e.dataTransfer.files[0]);  // this line!

  }, false);
}

function pointillize(context) {

  clearInterval(draw);  // before a new animation, clear setInterval

  // get new image data
  var imgData = context.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

  // clear canvas
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(0, 0, output.width, output.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)';
  ctx.fill();

  // store the setInterval in a variable so it can be cleared
  var draw = setInterval(function() {  

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

      // pick random integers x and y
      var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*output.height);
      var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*output.width);

      // get its position in the array
      var loc = (y*output.width + x)*4;

      // alpha in rgba goes from 0 to 1
      var r = imgData.data[loc];
      var g = imgData.data[loc+1];
      var b = imgData.data[loc+2];
      var a = 0.5;

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x, y, 2, 0, 2*Math.PI);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ', ' + b + ',' + a + ')';
      ctx.fill()
    }

  }, 50);  // closing setInterval()
}

document.addEventListener('click', clearCanvas, false);

function clearCanvas() {
  //interesting, so clearRect is working, for one frame...
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);  
}
```

Comment: You need to clearInterval when new image is dropped. 
Data from first image is in memory in first setInterval, which is working each 50 seconds. Then next time, second setInterval starts to work togather with first one, and so on. You can even try to freeze browser with number of dropped images.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I think I was just figuring it out as I finished typing my question. I declared draw a global variable. Inside pointillize() I clearInterval(draw), then a do draw = setInterval() and so on. Works perfectly.